# Old sci-fi book where a tunnel with varying values of pi leads to alien civilization

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm looking for a book I read as a kid (somewhere around 1985-1990 and probably published before this since it was translated to my language). The title says pretty much all I remember about the book. However the memory has stayed with me for a quarter of a century, so I'm desperately trying to find out what it was.

Other things I remember are the aliens looking relatively humanoid (not very sure about this), the aliens capable of shaping their surroundings with the power of the mind and advanced medicine. I also think you were able to travel faster near the center of the tunnel, along a shaft of some kind(?). I know this is all very vague, but I'm hoping someone can help.

Oh, and I do not think it was 'The Way' by Greg Bear.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The story you're remembering is [Eon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eon_%28novel%29), a novel by Greg Bear.  The tunnel is the Thistledown, a space-based alien artifact that is bigger inside than outside and has other interesting features.

Comment: Strictly speaking,  Thistledown was the asteroid the corridor was attached to: the corridor itself was called The Way. But despite the op's  statement to the contrary, I'm pretty sure this is the answer.

Comment: I've read the description of Eon and although it feels like that's the one I'm looking for, I'm still not quite sure. Unfortunately I only remember bits and pieces of the novel, so I can't be sure. Anyways Eon (and the rest of the series) sounds like a good read, being a huge sci-fi fan.

Comment: @Teemu Eon is a complete match for your story description including the varying values of pi, which is a very strong discriminator.

Comment: @KyleJones Yes it has to be that one. It just didn't feel quite right, but maybe the Finnish translation took some liberties, or my memory isn't as clear I thought. Anyways thank you all, I will have to read the series again. In the original language this time :)